# How do I know if my residual plot indicates equal variance?

Tags: residuals, fitting

I'm still confused about equal variance. Is this parabola in my residuals vs fitted plot indicative of equal variance since each fitted value has roughly the same vertical variance as at other values (the parabola is equally thick everywhere)? This residual plot suggests the original plot isn't linear though, right?

[image]

Comment: If you think the fitted curve is a fair summary -- and if this were my result, that would be my judgement -- then the first implication is that your functional form may need adjustment. That is the question to be answered before you worry about whether your residual variance is constant. To say more, we would need to see more detail on your variables, two or more of them.  Unless the data are confidential, you should be able to post them here.